# Shared Preferences not working in flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, mobile

Shared preferences is not working in my flutter project, I have updated my flutter,I have added the latest version of the sharedpreferences package to the pubspec.yaml, but still doesn't work.
[image]
When I hover over the underlined sharedpreferences, It says SharePreferences is undefined, And I have also imported the file at the top too.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AppCache {
  static const kUser = 'user';
  static const kOnboarding = 'onboarding';


  Future<void> invalidate() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool(kUser, false);
    await prefs.setBool(kOnboarding, false);
  }

  Future<void> cacheUser() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool(kUser, true);
  }

  Future<void> completeOnboarding() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool(kOnboarding, true);
  }

  Future<bool> isUserLoggedIn() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool(kUser) ?? false;
  }

  Future<bool> didCompleteOnboarding() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool(kOnboarding) ?? false;
  }
}
```

I updated my flutter, and also checked for the latest version of the package to make sure they correspond. I was expecting the imported sharedpreferences file at the top will be detected by flutter and treatred as a used import because I am using the SharePreferences class from it.

Comment: try command "flutter clean" followed by "flutter pub get" from terminal. If that doesn't not resolve the issue, quit code editor, reopen and run those 2 commands again

Comment: Hey, I suggest you to restart the dart analysis, commonly pinned down left corner side of the window in your android studio. This happens probably the dart no being read by the compiler due to update latest version of the package that you just added.

Comment: I have tried all that you have suggested but it still doesn't work, These are the packages in the  pubspec.yaml                                                                                                                         ```dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  provider: ^6.0.3
  flutter_colorpicker: ^1.0.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  go_router: ^4.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.0```

Comment: First I thought I messed with a file I shouldn't have so I created a different project to test the Sharedpreferences and I had the same issue in the new project

Comment: just to make sure, you are using async await with methods. Right?

Comment: yes, I am using async await

Comment: The problem is with package importing. I tested your code with 2.1.0 ver of SharedPref. your code is ok.  try removing the package from pubspec and follow these commands:
1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter pub add shared_preferences

Comment: Vivek please I have tried your method but it didn't work. Even if I create a whole new project and use shared_preferences in it, i get the same error. When I use version 2.0.15 of the shared_preferences it works but when I run the app, it tells me that some of the packages are outdated so I had to update all the packages in pubspec.yaml and then this error occurs

Comment: have you fixed it? @josephOforiTenkorang ??

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this while obtaining shared preferences.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Comment: The leading SharedPreferences is also unlined red and when I hover over any of the underlined SharedPreferences I get this feedback:                                                                                        Undefined class 'SharedPreferences'. (Documentation)  Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'SharedPreferences'.

Comment: Try to follow these steps:

1. flutter clean
2. Delete .gradle file which is under android folder.
3. Invalidate caches and restrat Android Studio. (File -> Invalidate caches)
4. flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

##### The solution is simple:

1. Added the latest version of the shared_preferences package to the pubspec.yaml
2. Close the code editor, reopen and run again.

Reload the code editor after add shared_preferences package to the pubspec.yaml